# Flutter.io (dart) app fails to launch on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, simulator, flutter

I have up-to-date OSX Sierra, up-to-date XCode with applicable plugins, and an iPhone 6 simulator open and ready.

I have followed all the directions at https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#ios-setup.

When I "flutter run" from Terminal, the app fails to install on the simulator with message:

**Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 6.**

Here is what Terminal said...

---

```
            Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 6 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                8.5s
Running Xcode build...                               24.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2017-11-22 13:13:38.122 xcodebuild[47659:25935636]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-13510/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetBuildContext.mm:757
    Details:  unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command <C0009:'CpResource app.flx':P12>
    Object:   <PBXTargetBuildContext: 0x7fccf1235200>
    Method:   -createCommandInvocationRecordFromInvocation:
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fccf2847ea0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    The following build commands failed:
        CopyPlistFile /Users/deborah/Desktop/chq_emulator/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
    (1 failure)
Xcode's output:
↳
    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = x86_64
        BUILD_DIR = /Users/deborah/Desktop/chq_emulator/build/ios
        ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator11.1
    
    === CLEAN TARGET leveldb-library OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    ... list of subsidiary infomation ...

    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone 6.
```

Anyone else out there with advice for how to get Flutter going on the simulator?

Comment: Did you try starting Xcode? It often loads additional updates when opened. It might as well have nothing to do, but it's quite a common issue.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :) . didn't help this time though.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671608/4479395. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your Xcode first and make sure that it's up-to-date. Open the `{flutter_project}/ios` build on Xcode then try to run the iOS project on the Simulator from there.

If you're still having issues, you can run this command on your Terminal. This should set the path for the active developer directory.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```