# Flutter : Not Connecting to IOS Simulator in Android Studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, simulator

I am following the Flutter Test Drive tutorial on the Flutter Docs. I installed XCode, cocoapods, ran `pods setup` etc.

However, in Android Studio, when I try to run IOS by clicking "Run IOS Simulator," it opens the simulator but fails to connect.

I also tried doing this from the terminal. Opened an IOS emulator and then ran `flutter run` in the app folder in terminal. I got an error `No devices attached.`

Comment: Are you able to run your emulator by running **open -a Simulator**? Also, please attach in your question the result of **flutter doctor**

Comment: That did the trick. **flutter doctor** helped me find the problem. My XCode installation was not complete. Now I have an error about python module "six"

Comment: Fixed the six module missing by doing `brew reinstall python@2` and `pip install six`

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped

Answer (score 227):

Please check whether you installed the latest version of Xcode.

After the installation, try to run the following command.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: I did not need to use this command but instead just needed to restart my MBP and Android Studio was working fine. It happened for me when I updated XCode.

Comment: Works! Android Studio immediately after executing this command,  detected iPhone simulator.

Comment: This works but can you explain what it does as well ?

Comment: Alternatively you can set command line tool from Xcode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745783/how-to-open-ios-simulator-in-android-studio-for-flutter-application/57018265#57018265

Comment: Yes, when I run it worked with M1 mac.

Comment: I'm using flutter. And this works on VS Code as well.

Comment: Excellent started working right away after executing the command.

Comment: It's working on iMac M1, macOS Ventura 13.1

Comment: Works fine. After executing command Android Studio detected my IOS Simulator

Answer (score 35):

As other people have suggested, it happens when you update XCode. So, run the command in terminal suggested by Muhammed

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Then, you probably have to run
`flutter clean`.
For it to run properly.

Answer (score 30):

I ran into the same problem but unfortunately, @MUHAMMED IQBAL PA's solution didn't suffice.
Running these two commands, however, resolved the problem:

1. As pointed out by others:

   ```
   sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
   ```
2. :

   ```
   sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
   ```

Comment: this is savage!

Comment: worked for me too! Thank you!!!

Comment: Please add an official link too in case if this gets updated:

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 15):

This error showed up after I updated my Xcode.

1. Open Terminal
2. Run the following command in Terminal

```html
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

3. Enter your device's password.

Your IDE (Android Studio or IntelliJ) will detect the IOS Simulator as soon as you click return.

Comment: What device password is this?

Comment: Password for sudo access (administrator password). Usually your Mac password.

Comment: listen carefully, i don't know you, you don't know me but i owe you my highest level of respect any man could imagine...;>

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem by flowing these steps and refreshing the list of simulators

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it happened to me when i have updated my Xcode, use this command to let Flutter recognize your Xcode again.
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 3):

I have to use three steps:

running this two commands :

1)
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

2)
flutter clean

3)

I have to select on Android studio Ide - (on the simulator select button drop down left hand side of main.dart showing) I have to select "Open IOS emulator".

Then the simulator run. And the simulator was Auto select on the emulator selected section.

I have used Android Studio Bumble Bee and Xcode 13.

The summary is, I think, I have to open the simulator first, then its come to online with Android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem on my MacBook.

iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 8.2.1)
    ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 9.0.0.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.

***Xcode was not updated. That is why IOS simulators are not supported.***

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you have agreed to Xcode licenses via running the command,

sudo xcodebuild -license

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this issue like this:

1. Open simulator
2. Go to "Device" in menu
3. Click "Erase all content and settings"

which this will delete all content and settings of the simulator but the problem of hide in the android studio devices will be fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had different issue why IOS simulator was not appearing in fresh installation - dart sdk was not configured. I've clicked run->run there it was showing that dart is not configured, I've added flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk in config and after that iphone simulator has appeared. Of course I followed other steps:
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch