# flutter run command does not launch in iOS Simulator

Tags: android, ios, ios-simulator, flutter

`flutter run` command does not launch in iOS Simulator. It launches good on Android simulator though. Using Mac. It seems to build the app only for Android.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671608/4479395. it worked for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. First ensure `flutter doctor` runs good and all necessary iOS components are installed.
2. Then manually opened the Simulator app in the Mac.
3. Then ensure the simulator shows up in `flutter devices`.
4. Now if you run the `flutter run` command, it built the app for iOS and ran on the iOS Simulator.

Comment: "Then ensure the simulator shows up in flutter devices.". This step seems particularly problematic :/

Comment: I had Xcode installed and was running the Simulator, but `flutter run` didn't seem to see it. Running `flutter doctor` showed there were some commands that needed to be run after installed Xcode. Doing that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: NOTE: You can use flutter run -d PREFIX_OF_DEVICE_NAME to start it on a specific device. So for iPhone on ios simulator, have the simulator running, then run flutter run -d iPhone - which you will see is the FIRST part of the name of the device when you run `flutter devices`.  And you can only launch the ios flutter project if the simulator is ALREADY running, which you can launch from the command line on mac, by running `open -a Simulator`

Answer (score 1):

run flutter doctor, you may found a problem relating to Xcode, type the two commands provided to fix the problem and will appear.