# iOS simulator not working or taking so much time in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I tried to run an app in an iOS Simulator it get stuck in `Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...`. Sometimes, after a couple hours, it goes forward, so It seems that the problem here it's that it takes soo long.

In case you want to know, my computer is MBP i5 8gb

Results when execute `flutter run -v` on iOS Simulator:

```
testing flutter run -v -d BAC497EA-D54E-4B34-AE01-8ACB239AD7F5
[  +60 ms] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[        ] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +17 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 5391447fae6209bb21a89e6a5a6583cac1af9b4b
[        ] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 5 weeks ago
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +18 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.0.0-0-g5391447fa
[ +471 ms] executing: /Users/leonardodominguez/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/leonardodominguez/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
          emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:1
[  +13 ms] executing: idevice_id -h
[  +64 ms] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl list --json devices
[+2287 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
[  +21 ms] executing: /usr/bin/defaults read /Users/leonardodominguez/Desktop/Projects/flutter/course/testing/ios/Runner/Info CFBundleIdentifier
[ +284 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/defaults read /Users/leonardodominguez/Desktop/Projects/flutter/course/testing/ios/Runner/Info CFBundleIdentifier
[        ] $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
[  +41 ms] Building Runner.app for BAC497EA-D54E-4B34-AE01-8ACB239AD7F5.
[  +36 ms] /Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --strong --target=flutter --no-link-platform --incremental --packages
/Users/leonardodominguez/Desktop/Projects/flutter/course/testing/.packages --output-dill build/app.dill --depfile build/snapshot_blob.bin.d package:testing/main.dart
[  +15 ms] executing: script /dev/null /usr/bin/log stream --style syslog --predicate processImagePath CONTAINS "BAC497EA-D54E-4B34-AE01-8ACB239AD7F5"
[ +160 ms] [DEVICE LOG] Filtering the log data using "processImagePath CONTAINS "BAC497EA-D54E-4B34-AE01-8ACB239AD7F5""
[+3384 ms] Building bundle
[   +2 ms] Writing asset files to build/flutter_assets
[ +350 ms] Wrote build/flutter_assets
[  +30 ms] Using legacy Xcode build system.
[  +23 ms] executing: [/Users/leonardodominguez/Desktop/Projects/flutter/course/testing/ios/] /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/leonardodominguez/Documents/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (5 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/leonardodominguez/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.21.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone X                  • BAC497EA-D54E-4B34-AE01-8ACB239AD7F5 • ios         • iOS 12.1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671608/4479395. it worked for me.

Comment: same issue for me it take too long

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Most of the time it hangs for me too. Once it actually loaded the app for me in a matter of seconds, but that's the only time it's ever loaded. up to date Xcode and flutter doctor no issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution to this problem. If you run into it, the problem was iCloud. I moved my projects to my user's directory—iCloud does not mess there— and that fixed it.