# ProcessException: Process timed out: when xode build Done Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

After Xcode code build `flutter run`

```
ProcessException: Process timed out:
  Command: /usr/bin/env xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Debug -quiet -workspace
  Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner
  BUILD_DIR=/Users/Huzeifah/Documents/flutter_development/test_app/build/ios
  -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64
  SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/w8/nf0h0vbj01v4qz3wbk07fvnr0000gn/T/flu
  tter_build_log_pipe.O5hXp2/pipe_to_stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true
  COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO -showBuildSettings
```

All version information when run `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-PK)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
      ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)            

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

When I run flutter. Xocde build done then give the Error ProceesTimw out. Then I try every thing that i can try. I install new vwesion of Xcode 11.4.1 and flutter new version 1.17 stable [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5FEb.png)

Comment: There are issues with flutter and Xcode tools. The issue is still under review. You can alternatively open Runner.xworkspace in Xcode and build there. For hot reload & restart, you can install Dart Dev Tools and run a debugger on chrome. Maybe this will get your development going.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had the same issue and resolved it by moving my project out of a folder that iCloud was backing up. I had moved to a place with slower wifi, so my project kept hanging. Now, it loads faster than it did before.

Credit here ([iOS simulator not working or taking so much time in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000681/ios-simulator-not-working-or-taking-so-much-time-in-flutter))

Answer (score 1):

This  usually happens when you update xcode to fix this use `Flutter upgrade` in your general terminal and go to your project code editor and run `Flutter clean` and run `flutter run` if you face any other issues let me know......