# Android studio does not want to connect to ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I just installed flutter on my mac and xcode etc, I am trying to run the flutter demo app on my simulator and it keeps telling showing me no device connected regardless of the fact that my simulator is online and running, I can't seem to figure out what the problem is, if I can get help to solve this I will be very grateful.

**Flutter Doctor**
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G66, locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.0)
    ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

.....
thanks guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : Not Connecting to IOS Simulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318475/flutter-not-connecting-to-ios-simulator-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You need Xcode version 11.0.0 at a minimum. Try updating it from the AppStore, it should work after that. Xcode is required to build and sign iOS Apps, so if you do not have a valid version, Flutter can't build to those devices.

From your error message: "[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.0) ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0."

Comment: without xcode 11.0 i can't run flutter on my simulator? what if i am on a macOS high sierra and I can't run the latest macOS catalina?

Comment: @Octagod Yes, and you will not be able to build to a real device. Android should work fine though.

Comment: is there any way around this?

Comment: @Octagod Maybe you could try downgrading Flutter to an older version that works with Xcode 10.0. Obviously thats not a great solution but I don't know of any others.

Comment: Ok, i will try that

Comment: @Octagod Good luck, feel free to accept the answer if you feel like it helped.